# SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_LOGIN missing in 3.1

Tags: java, spring-security

I've been using something like this on my login form so the user doesn't have to retype the username again if he mistypes the password:

```
<input type="text" name="j_username" value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_LOGIN}" />
```

However, it seems the last login is no longer stored on that session variable. Moreover, the constant seems to be removed from [WebAttributes since 3.1](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/WebAttributes.html) ([3.0 still has it](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/WebAttributes.html#LAST_USERNAME)).

So, is there a way I can achieve the same result in 3.1?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to customize the [`AuthenticationFailureHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#form-login-flow-handling) to cache the username prior to redirecting the user back to the login page.

Comment: I can't find any details on how to do this (ie subclass SimpleURLAuthenticationFailureHandler, how to access to the default URL so you can continue to use it, etc)  Why isn't this provided out of the box?  It seems truly bizarre to force people to do this when its such a common feature.  Why make it this hard?  I've wasted hours researching this on something that should've taken all of 5 minutes to implement.